# Can I apply for jobs that didn't mention anything about visa sponsorship?

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, applications, relocation, visa

There are a lot of positions in some countries like Netherlands but less than one percent of them mentioned either support or not support the visa sponsorship.

So is it professional to apply for these jobs when I need a work visa and work permit?

Comment: Then it will be assumed you are already permitted to work in the Netherlands.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY So you mean I should mention in my resume that I need a visa?

Comment: @Daniyal Not in resume, in the cover letter.

Comment: @SouravGhosh this may be location dependent - in Australia we expect visa/right-to-work status in the resume, usually near the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's perfectly fine to *apply*, in the worst case you'll get rejected. You don't really risk anything. However, in some situations it's less likely to get rejected:

1. If the job and the salary allow you to get a blue card* or something similar, it shouldn't matter for the company. Well, unless they need someone who can start working right tomorrow. In this case, it's perfectly fine to apply, because you would be able to relatively quickly get a work permit without any help from the company.

(*Blue card is a residence and work permit for highly skilled workers, used in many EU countries.)

2. If getting a work permit would require the company to prove that they can't find anyone else for this position, gather additional documents etc, they probably don't want foreigners to apply.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, find out the point of contact from the job posting, and ask the question directly to the people responsible for handling the recruitment process, whether they have a visa sponsorship or not.

This will save some time and effort from both the sides to going forward with the process only to be rejected because a pre-requisite was not met, and will help you to focus your attention to the ones where your requirements of visa sponsorship will be taken care.